# printf byte to hex string strange output

Tags: hex, printf

The following simple code produces strange output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "/tmp/sha.h"
#define DIGEST 64

//taken from coreutils 8.5 - produces 64-byte sha digest and puts it into resblock
extern int sha512_stream(FILE *stream, void *resblock);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char sha[DIGEST];
memset(sha, 0, DIGEST);
FILE *stream;
stream = fopen("/bin/less", "r");
sha512_stream(stream, (void *) sha);
fclose(stream);

char buf[2] = {10, 32};
printf("%02x\n", sha[0]);
printf("%02x\n", buf[0]);

return 0;}
```

Gives the output:  
ffffffa9  
  0a

The first byte of sha is A9, but where are the padding F's coming from?

On Ubuntu Linux 10.10 with gcc 4.4.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(char)` defaults to `(signed char)` on Linux x86, and because `printf()` uses `stdarg` the `(signed char)` is being promoted implicitly to `(int)` resulting in sign extension.  You'll need to declare it `(unsigned char)` to get the expected behavior.  (There is no way to pass type information through `stdarg`, so default promotions are performed on arguments.)